# It's possible to create user control like webforms in MVC 5 with razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to have in my website `aspnet mvc 5` application, some kind of user control that work as an ajax image uploader so i can put it where i need in my website.
It's possible this? i could think in create a partial view with the code but it must have `javascript` and i don't want that. Is there another way? to have JS and Razor in a view that can be used in different places as a user control?

maybe using a `@helper`? but in this case i don't know if helpers can have `JavaScript`

Comment: Take a look at Html.RenderPartial. That will inject your html partial into the area you call the helper.

Comment: But with this i need to have javascript in the partial and i dont want that

Comment: Are you worried about duplicate JS?

Comment: But it's a good practice or should i need something "special" to make the javascript code to work being this a partial view? what about `@section head` sections in a layout?

Comment: Maybe you should give a example of what you are trying. I can pinpoint the issue better then.

Comment: You can treat a partial view just like any other razor view.  That means you can add script tags to include separate `.js` files.  If you then want to have access to the partial across your entire site, simply make sure it's in the `~/Views/Shared/` folder.  Furthermore, if you require an action to be run before the partial, you should use `Html.RenderAction()` instead.

Comment: I always heard that putting javascript in a partial view is not a good practice. I will try the partial view option

Comment: Technically, you shouldn't put it in the view.  It's a better idea to include it in your main layout view so that it's only included once.  That means the script is then available to you whenever you include the partial.  The real problem is when you include a partial multiple times with embedded JavaScript